# How does evaporator coil absorb heat when a cool liquid is passed inside it?

Tags: thermodynamics, absorption, cooling

My question is how does evaporator coil inside a refrigerator cools the inside atmosphere by absorbing heat?    I am fully confused, how the heat absorption happens? This technically sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

the evaporator coil contains very cold liquid refrigerant- colder than the inside of the refrigerator. Heat from inside the refrigerator diffuses into the evaporator coils, and the refrigerant inside picks up heat from inside the refrigerator and in so doing turns into a vapor, which then leaves the evaporator and enters the compressor.

Comment: You should add that the liquid boils and thereby removes the heat of vaporization from the coil tubing.